# what's meaning of this code from the libdispatch (apple-open-source)?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, libdispatch

I am having hard time understanding the following code:

```
struct dispatch_block_private_data_s {
    DISPATCH_BLOCK_PRIVATE_DATA_HEADER();
    static void* operator new(size_t) = delete;
    static void* operator new [] (size_t) = delete;
    explicit inline DISPATCH_ALWAYS_INLINE dispatch_block_private_data_s(
            dispatch_block_flags_t flags, voucher_t voucher,
            pthread_priority_t priority, dispatch_block_t block) noexcept :
            dbpd_magic(), dbpd_flags(flags), dbpd_atomic_flags(),
            dbpd_performed(), dbpd_priority(priority), dbpd_voucher(voucher),
            dbpd_block(block), dbpd_group(), dbpd_queue(), dbpd_thread()
    {
        // stack structure constructor, no releases on destruction
        _dispatch_block_private_data_debug("create, block: %p", dbpd_block);
    }
};
```

What's the `static void* operator new(size_t) = delete;` and why `inline` func in `struct`? Who can help me learn with these code ? Here is the [code address](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/master/src/block.cpp#L49)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the `.cpp` extension. This is [C++](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) code.

1. The `operator ... = delete` syntax says that this operator should be suppressed, generating a compiler warning if you try to use it.
2. The `inline` qualifier is a performance optimization. To quote from [The C++ Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840):

   > The `inline` specifier is a hint to the compiler that it should attempt to generate code for a call of [the function] inline rather than laying down the code for the function once and then calling through the usual function call mechanism.

   If (a) a function is small; and (b) performance is of paramount concern, you can use `inline` qualifier so that the compiler will, effectively, just insert the code of the function wherever you use it rather than saving it as a function and calling it you normally would. This saves the modest overhead of calling the function.

If you need help understanding C++, I’d suggest you check out [these resources](https://isocpp.org/get-started).